# One local storage JavaScript for fields on different pages

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Three different web pages have three contenteditable areas each (`content1`, `content2`, and `content3`).

Each page links to one JavaScript which uses local storage to store the user's input and present it again on their return.

When I change the content on one page, it changes the content in the same editable area all three pages.

I want each page to be able to use the same script to save it's own data independently of the other pages.

I've tried adding page location (url) to the local storage key, to get each page to use the same script to store and retrieve it's own data, but I can't get it to work. Am new to JavaScript - would be grateful for any help. Thanks!

```
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad);

function onLoad() {
    checkEdits();
}

// Get page location
var loc = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);

// Add location to local storage key
function checkEdits() {
    if (localStorage.userEdits1 != null) {
        var userEdits1 = (loc + userEdits1);
        document.getElementById('content1').innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits1;
    }

    if (localStorage.userEdits2 != null) {
        var userEdits2 = (loc + userEdits2);
        document.getElementById('content2').innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits2;
    }

    if (localStorage.userEdits3 != null) {
        var userEdits3 = (loc + userEdits3);
        document.getElementById('content3').innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits3;
    }
};

document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    console.log(e.keyCode);

    saveEdits();
};

function saveEdits() {
    // Get editable elements
    var editElem1 = document.getElementById('content1');
    var editElem2 = document.getElementById('content2');
    var editElem3 = document.getElementById('content3');

    // Get edited elements contents
    var userVersion1 = editElem1.innerHTML;
    var userVersion2 = editElem2.innerHTML;
    var userVersion3 = editElem3.innerHTML;

    // Add page location to storage key
    var userEdits1 = (loc + userEdits1);
    var userEdits2 = (loc + userEdits2);
    var userEdits3 = (loc + userEdits3);

    // Save the content to local storage
    localStorage.userEdits1 = userVersion1;
    localStorage.userEdits2 = userVersion2;
    localStorage.userEdits3 = userVersion3;
};

function clearLocal() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to clear your notes on this page?')) {
        localStorage.setItem("userEdits1", "");
        localStorage.setItem("userEdits2", "");
        localStorage.setItem("userEdits3", "");

        document.getElementById('content1').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('content2').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('content3').innerHTML = "";

        alert('Notes cleared');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem of your script is this:

```
localStorage.userEdits1
```

To access the property of an object with a string (e.g. stored in a variable) you have to use the bracket notation:

```
locationStorage[userEdits1]
```

But I would propose a slightly more generic (and, imho, cleaner) solution...

Store the content of the editable elements in an object

```js
var cache = {
    <elementX id>: <content>,
    <elementY id>: <content>,
    <elementZ id>: <content>,
    ...
};
```

And then store this "cache" in the local storage with a page-specific key

```js
localStorage.setItem(window.location.pathName, JSON.stringify(cache));
```

A possible implementation could be:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', checkEdits);
getContentEditables().forEach(function(editable) {
  // This prevents the function to execute on every keyup event 
  // Instead it will only be executed 100ms after the last keyup
  var debouncedFunc = debounce(100, function(e) {
    saveEdits();
  });

  editable.addEventListener("keyup", debouncedFunc);
});


function checkEdits() {
  var cache = localStorage.getItem(window.location.pathName);

  if (cache !== null) {
    cache = JSON.parse(cache);

    Object.keys(cache)
      .forEach(function(key) {
        var element = document.getElementById(key);

        if (element !== null) {
          element.innerHTML = cache[key];
        }
      });
  }
}

function saveEdits() {
  var cache = {};

  getContentEditables().forEach(function(element) {
    cache[element.id] = element.innerHTML;
  });

  localStorage.setItem(window.location.pathName, JSON.stringify(cache));
};

function clearLocal() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to clear your notes on this page?')) {
    localStorage.removeItem(window.location.pathName);

    getContentEditables().forEach(function(element) {
      element.innerHTML = "";
    });

    alert('Notes cleared');
  }
}


// helper
function getContentEditables() {
  var elements = [];

  document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable]")
    .forEach(function(element) {
      if (element.id) {
        elements.push(element);
      }
    });

  return elements;
}

function debounce(timeout, func) {
  var timeoutId;

  return function() {
    var that = this,
        args = arguments;

    clearTimeout(timeoutId);

    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
      func.apply(that, args);
    }, timeout);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful, detailed response. The code works exactly as I hoped and will help me learn a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
localStorage[userEdits1]
```

Instead of

```
localStorage.userEdits1
```